# Where can i find sample for symbian app for sending sms?

Tags: symbian

I have Nokia N70. Need to code some applications which can send a lot of sms one by one (sms spamming), smth like:

```
for(int i=11111; i < 99999; i++)
{
   SendSms("+385 655" + i.ToString(), "Hello, World");
}
```

in this dummy sample lets say +385 stands for Croatia country and 655 is operator code.

Comment: What do you need SMS spam application for?

Answer (score 1):

N70 is the old Series60 2nd edition. We try to not write new C++ code for that version. Use the example code for J2ME JSR-120 instead. You can find that at http://java.sun.com

Answer (score 1):

The easy way to send SMS in Symbian is through the RSendAs API. There is [an example at Forum Nokia](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/CS001307_-_Symbian_C++:_Sending_an_SMS).

However, this API may not exist on 2nd edition. If it doesn't, you should be able to use CSmsClientMtm and related classes, for which there is also [an example](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/Sending_SMS_in_S60_3rd_Edition_-_MTM).

Comment: The example is for Series60 3rd edition. However, it does quote the smssend example from S60 2nd FP2 SDK as a reference.